# use OR in if codition to print reverse results in php

Tags: php

I am trying echo result "OK" if ( 1 either both ) variable true, i did so far like this

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$point= "select points from users where id = $user_id "; // in db right now points = 2000
$flag= "select m_boost from users where id = $user_id "; // in db right now flag = 1
?>
<div class="box border">
<div class="box-title">
<?php
if($point < 1000 || $flag = 0) {
echo "not ok";
} else { ?>
echo "ok";
<?php }?>
</div>
```

**it's working if i do like this**

```
if(($point == '2000') || ($flag == '0') ){
```

but i don't want == operator for $point i want less than < $point < '999'

**The problem is :** 
Keep getting result " Not Ok " even one variable (flag = 1) is true in db

```
Expected Results:
```

i want to print "OK" if $point > 1000 or flag == 1,

Comment: So you actually want `&&`?

Comment: You need to change `$flag = 0` to `$flag == 0` in  `if($point < 1000 || $flag = 0)`.

Comment: @goarage Go can you check my ans ?

Comment: @krishnpatel, sir i want to keep on reverse order, i want echo ok in else statement

Comment: @Sean, tried changing but sitll not w0rking

Comment: @GoargeGo you can check my ans now

Comment: @krishnpatel, your answer is totally different, we need to keep on same question pattern for inverse condition application

Comment: @krishnpatel, test my answer on this post it have same question formation and worked 100%  answered by ccKep[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997833/use-or-within-if-else-condition-by-inverse-condition-order-in-php/41999855#41999855]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!$flag && $point < 1000)
{
    echo "Not OK";
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
```

**Writing this into a truth-table:**

```
flag        point       result
0           < 1000      Not OK
1           < 1000      OK
0           >=1000      OK
1           >=1000      OK
```

Worked for me now as per my question

i think we are all here for some contribution reason, flagging down a question is not a way, if you got solution than respond otherwise my question was 100% clear.

Comment: answered by ccKep[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997833/use-or-within-if-else-condition-by-inverse-condition-order-in-php/41999855#41999855]

Answer (score 1):

try this

when you using OR condition you should careful about condition and login. you  should implement logic in if condition instead of else.

```
    if($point > 1000 || $flag ==1) {
        echo "ok";
    }else {
      echo 'Not ok'
    }
```

or AS YOU WANT

```
if($point < 1000 ) {
        echo "Not ok";
    }else if($flag ==0) {
      echo 'Not ok'
    }esle {
      echo 'ok'
    }
```

or you can use this way

```
$a=false;


       if($point < 1000 ) {
                    $a=true;
                }else if($flag ==0) {
                  $a=true;
                }esle {
                  $a=false;
                }
    // you can use this variable in your condition.

    if($a) {
                echo "ok";
            }else {
              echo 'Not ok'
            }
```

Comment: sir, i want to keep reverse pattern this is straight pattern

Comment: i want to print ok in else condition

Comment: @GoargeGo what about else if ?

Comment: if i use else if i need to repeat code this is logical solution but i need to replace lot of lines

Comment: then you need to do it. because there is OR condition. I have given both way. now decide which way you want to do. first one is better.

Comment: better if we do something in same example i shared in question because it taken from already implemented code where i have added 2 condition by OR

Comment: it is easy you simply  put you else code in if and if into else. it will work.

Comment: yup correct, but i need to shuffle code of 50 files if i not found solution in same question format it will be great and i will appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134652/discussion-between-goarge-go-and-krishn-patel).

Comment: @karish patel, i want reserve condition solution

Comment: will else if condition work if both condition not TRUE or TRUE

Answer (score 0):

```
$flag = 0
```

You're setting the variable's value to 0.
Example:

```
$flag = 1;
if($a < $b || $flag = 0){ //$flag's value is 0 now.
...
...
}
```

In conditions comparisons, the right operator is "==".

```
if($point < 1000 || $flag == 0) {
```

[**List of comparison operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

---

> but i don't want == operator for $point i want less than < $point <
>   '999'

Didn't fully understood your goals, but maybe:

For checking a value in a range the right logical operator should be "`and`" (`&&`);

```
if($point > 0 && $point < 999){
```

[**List of logical operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

**Update:**

> if $point > 1000 or flag == 1

```
if($point > 1000 || $flag == 1){
   echo "ok"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using OR, if the first condition is met the second is disregarded.

Also, make sure you use double equals (`==`) for comparison, not single equals (`=`) which means assignment.

Therefore you want to replace this:

```
if($point < 1000 || $flag = 0) {
```

With one of these:

*SWAPPED AROUND*

```
if($flag == 0 || $point < 1000) {
```

or

*USING `&&` INSTEAD*

```
if($point < 1000 && $flag == 0) {
```

Depending on what behaviour you're looking for. It's a little unclear - so any additional clarification from you would be helpful.

Once you get something that you think is working, try to test all possible combinations so that you can be confident it works how you wish.

Comment: let me try, and to make it more clear i want to print ok <br>if $point > 1000 or flag == 1, hope it's clear now

Comment: i have tried both both above solution not working still getting result " Not Ok "

Comment: @GoargeGo, why havn't you mentioned that in your question? check the update part in my solution.

Comment: @OfirBaruch, i want to echo " Ok " in else statement because i need to keep on reverse condition order